# How to fix "x is not a function" error on AOT

Tags: angularjs, angular2-aot, ng-lightning

I am running Angular AOT using 3rd party library (tether.js) for `ng-lightning`. JIT works fine, but after building it with AOT & Rollup, I get the following error (tether.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: S is not a function
```

I have the following definition inside System.config.js:

```
map: {  'tether': 'npm:tether/dist/js' }
```

and inside packages:

```
packages: {  'tether': { defaultExtension: 'js' } }
```

Is there a better way to import so I won't get this error?